Weird behaviour when using amssymb, hphantom, bm and widehat
Disclaimer: this issue may be loosely related to this one: Weird \widehat behaviour caused by packages amsmath, amssymb and fouriernc
Using the following MWE:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}
    \noindent
    $\widehat{a}$, \bm{$\widehat{a}$}\\
    Some text\\
    $\widehat{a}$, \bm{$\widehat{a}$}\\
    \hphantom{The Headless Horseman}\\
    $\widehat{a}$, \bm{$\widehat{a}$}\\
    $\widehat{a}$, \bm{$\widehat{a}$}
\end{document}

Produces the following output when compiling with LuaLaTeX (TeXLive 2023):

into which the widehat are way too large after the hphantom. What is particularly weird is that if I comment out the \usepackage{amssymb} line or the \hphantom line, it works as expected. It's as if either hphantom or amssymb were having side effect that screw up the widehat function in \bm mode.
What's even weirder is that asking for the macro expansion of \bm, and \widehat adding \show\command (replacing command by the corresponding one) before and after the \hphantom yields the same output, namely:
> \bm=macro:
#1->\protect \bm  {#1}.
l.21    \show\bm
> \widehat=macro:
#1->\@mathmeasure \z@ \textstyle {#1}\ifdim \wd \z@ >\tw@ em\mathaccent "055B{#
1}\else \mathaccent "0362{#1}\fi .
l.22    \show\widehat

I'm completely lost here, and if anyone has an idea what's going on, I'm more than interested. This would avoid me from drowning in abysses of madness...

A workaround would be to use {\hphantom{The Headless Horseman}} instead of \hphantom{The Headless Horseman} (note the extra group).

bm is a bit suspect with luatex but you see the same in pdftex,looking...

@cabohah Thanks, I also noticed that replacing it with an empty \mbox{} solved the problem, but it's not really satisfactory as I am to include these widehats into a document already several hundreds of pages long, which may already contain a few \hphantoms here and there... :-/

amsfonts \wideaccent  is affected by the current contents of box 0 which is unfortunate, this seems to fix it (\bm really should be inside the math although actually it makes no difference here)
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{bm}


\makeatletter
\newbox\wide@box
\@ifpackageloaded{stix}{}{%
    \xdef\widehat#1{\noexpand\@mathmeasure\wide@box\textstyle{#1}%
      \noexpand\ifdim\noexpand\wd\wide@box>\tw@ em%
      \mathaccent"0\hexnumber@\symAMSb 5B{#1}%
      \noexpand\else\mathaccent"0362{#1}\noexpand\fi}
    \xdef\widetilde#1{\noexpand\@mathmeasure\wide@box\textstyle{#1}%
      \noexpand\ifdim\noexpand\wd\wide@box>\tw@ em%
      \mathaccent"0\hexnumber@\symAMSb 5D{#1}%
      \noexpand\else\mathaccent"0365{#1}\noexpand\fi}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \noindent
    $\widehat{a}$, $\bm{\widehat{a}$}\\
    Some text\\
    $\widehat{a}$, $\bm{\widehat{a}$}\\
    \mbox{}\setbox0\hbox{kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk}\\
    $\widehat{a}$, \tracingall$\bm{\widehat{a}$}\\
    $\widehat{a}$, $\bm{\widehat{a}$}
\end{document}



Actually the problem isn't just in amsfonts as the above wording implies: it's a bm issue. I may be able to avoid it there without changing amsfonts (although it would be simpler if \widehat was robust)

Thanks for the answer! Could you please consider editing it to make it more explicit / understandable for non-LaTeX experts? Something like "explain me mike I am 5 years old"? I'm not very fluent in LaTeX but would yet like to be able to understand the "why" behind this strange behaviour. Where is the problem actually located, what is causing it, etc. I am not only searching for a direct solution (as mentioned in comments, an empty mbox does the trick), but am also interested in understanding how I could solve things like this in the future.

No sorry I posted as far as I got, to help others looking and I'll update the answer when I see what's wrong but I need to work on the day job for a while first, I'll come back to this later. For now just take this as confirming it is not anything you did wrong but is a bug in latex/bm/amssymb somewhere @mranvick

@mranvick try now

No problem, if I interpreted your last comment correctly and it was about testing the fixed MWE that you provide, I can confirm that it solves the issue.

@mranvick thanks for confirming, you can use that fix, I suspect I'll actually adjust things in bm rather than amsfonts (probably better and easier as I have direct write access to bm) but that patch is safe enough in any case.
